# Performance issue in backbone template

Tags: performance, backbone.js

I am having a performance issue with backbone template.

The situation is I have collection of model, each model have a field called 'isSelected'.

I need to render this collection with a template for each individual model. The 'isSelected' field is used for setting the checkbox in the template.

For the sake of discussion, the template is as following.

```
<div class='thumbnail'>
  <input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' {[ if (isSelected) { ]} checked='checked'{[ } ]}
</div>
```

When I need to make the checkbox all selected, I will update the field to true for each model in the collection.

The code I used is

```
this.collection.each(function(e) {
    e.set("isSelected", true);
});
```

However, this way is very slow, for a collection contains 25 items, it will take almost 10 sec to make all checkbox 'checked'.

I am expecting that it should least than 1 sec, if i use plain jquery.

Is there any problems with this approach? what's the best approach for this kind problem?

Comment: Can you post the minimum amount of code that reproduces the 10 sec delay on http://jsfiddle.net/. A simple each and render on 25 models should never take that long.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set `isSelected` to `true` as default in the model? That way you don't have to loop through the collection to set each of them to true.

Comment: yes, but it's only one use case. I also want to control the checkbox based on certain condition.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's taking up all the processing time with the amount of code you posted. My first guess would be the render function is being called multiple times. Creating and destroying templates kills performance. If you hard more code posted it might be easy to spot any problem areas.

You should render all of the HTML nodes that could possibility be need. After they are rendered save a jquery selector and use that to toggle the selected.

Most of the time it isn't JS or Backbone that is the bottleneck. It's that JavaScript is triggering the DOM, CSS or reflows constituently and the browser is doing way too much work.

I'm building a PerfView for for backbone. It can render a collection with 1,000,000 models and scroll at 120FPS on chrome. The code is on Github at: https://github.com/puppybits/BackboneJS-PerfView. There's a lot of optimizations in there and comments in the code. One of the techniques in there is sure to solve your issue.